# How to create a custom dynamic logger?

Tags: magento2, log

I need a dynamic logger using monologger. My problem statement is, I need a logger which can be named dynamically when I call it. For example I use a bill.php, I need the logger to generate a log file called debug_bill.log. The file name of log should be made in a dynamic way. Any ideas on that?

Comment: https://techurbane.com/how-to-add-custom-logs-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this all you need to do is:

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Logger\Handler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filesystem" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Logger\Logger">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customLogger</argument>
            <argument name="handlers"  xsi:type="array">
                <item name="system" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Logger\Handler</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> vendor/module/Logger/Handler.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Model\Logger;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface;
use Monolog\Logger;

class Handler extends \Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base
{
    /**
     * Logging level
     * @var int
     */
    protected $loggerType = Logger::INFO;

    /**
     * File name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $filePath;

    /**
     * @var DriverInterface
     */
    protected $filesystem;

    public function __construct(
        DriverInterface $filesystem
    ) {
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    }

    public function setLoggerData($loggerName)
    {
        $this->customLoggerFileName = $loggerName;
        if (!isset($this->customLoggerFileName) || empty($this->customLoggerFileName)) {
            $this->customLoggerFileName = 'custom_log';
        }
        $this->filePath = '/var/log/' . $this->customLoggerFileName . '.log'; 
        parent::__construct(
            $this->filesystem,
            null,
            $this->filePath
        );
    }
}
```

> vendor/module/Logger/Logger.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Logger;

class Logger extends \Monolog\Logger {
}
```

> In order to use the logger:

Your desired file:

```
public function __construct(\Vendor\Module\Logger\Logger $logger,
\Vendor\Module\Logger\Handler $handler){
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->handler = $handler;
}

public function test(){
        $this->handler->setLoggerData('testing_debug');
        $this->logger->info('testing');

}
```

Comment: This will not work if 2 files have different log file names. For example, In controller I need to log in controller.log and from predispatch controller observer i have observer.log file, in this case, it is always logging into observer.log

Comment: It can log in 2 different file. You have to just call $this->handler->setLoggerData('testing_debug');

Answer (score 0):

for Magento 2.4.2 before version use this

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Custom message'); 
$logger->info(print_r($object->getData(), true));
```

for Magento 2.4.2 or after version use this

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new  \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
$logger->info(print_r($object->getData(), true));
```

for Magento 2.4.3 version use this

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
$logger->info(print_r($object->getData(), true));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and time. I know about these zend logger, but I am not in need of this. I need a custom logger which can be used globally and dynamically with one import and fn call !